# Why isn't counting the reactions

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

My goal here is to count the reactions but when i react on the reaction the bot doesn't count and if two people react i wont get the two reactions.

```
collector.on('end', (collected) => {
  let i = 0;

  const collectedembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();

  collected.forEach((value) => {
    i++;

    collectedembed.setTitle(question);
    if (i === 1) {
      collectedembed.addField('1st option', value.content);
    } else if (i === 2) {
      collectedembed.addField('2nd option', value.content);
    }
  });

  message.channel.send({ embeds: [collectedembed] }).then((poll) => {
    poll.react('1️⃣');
    poll.react('2️⃣');

    const filter2 = (reaction, user) => {
      return ['1️⃣', '2️⃣'].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id;
    };

    const collector2 = poll.createReactionCollector({ filter: filter2, time: 5000 });

    collector2.on('end', (collected) => {
      poll.channel.send(
        `reacted with 1️⃣ ${poll.reactions.cache.get('1️⃣').count} users \n reacted with 2️⃣${
          poll.reactions.cache.get('2️⃣').count
        } users`,
      );
    });
  });
});
```

here is an image example of my issue:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should count the amount of each of the reactions received by using the `<Collection>` parameter of the `<ReactionCollector>.on('end', ...)` method's callback function:

```js
collector2.on('end', collected => {
    poll.channel.send(collected.map(reaction => `${reaction.emoji} » ${reaction.count} Users`).join('\n'));
});
```

Comment: yeap thats work, tahnks!